# How do I catch the exception thrown by the code inside a Guava retryer?

Tags: java, java-8, guava

I have a Guava retryer around some code:

```
Retryer<Boolean> retryer = RetryerBuilder.<Boolean>newBuilder()
    .retryIfExceptionOfType(Exception.class)
    .withStopStrategy(MoreStopStrategies.liveStopAfterAttempt(retries))
    .withWaitStrategy(MoreWaitStrategies.liveExponentialWait(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, retrySleep, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
    .build();

try {
  retryer.call(() -> {
    return doStuff();
  });
} catch (ExecutionException | RetryException e) {
  throw Throwables.propagate(e);
}
```

Let's say `doStuff()` throws an `ArithmeticException`. How do I catch that outside the `retryer.call()`?

So the retryer will try a couple times, fail, and enter into the `catch (ExecutionException | RetryException e)` block. How would I retrieve the `ArithmeticException` inside there?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at `e.getCause()`. But `ArithmeticException`s are easy to detect and avoid: better to check for zero before dividing (or whatever) than to catch and retry. Note that unchecked exceptions aren't really meant to indicate retryable problems.

Comment: @AndyTurner Great, thanks! Yea, I just used `ArithmeticException` as an example since it was the first thing that popped into my head lol.

Comment: Look at implementing your own `RetryListener`. Seems that it is the most convenient way to realise what you want. Also you can try implementing your own `StopStrategy` or retrying `Predicate`, but as for me it is odd as soon as you are not gonig to stop attempts.

Comment: Er, I don't think Guava has a Retryer.  Where is that coming from?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Looks like https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a faulty pattern. You say that any exception is ok to retry. An `ArithmeticException` will then be ok to retry. This is not what you want.

This is how retries should be implemented. Note the comment on the second line.

```
Retryer<Boolean> retryer = RetryerBuilder.<Boolean>newBuilder()
//  .retryIfExceptionOfType(Exception.class)
    .withStopStrategy(MoreStopStrategies.liveStopAfterAttempt(retries))
    .withWaitStrategy(MoreWaitStrategies.liveExponentialWait(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, retrySleep, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
    .build();

void doStuff() {
  try {
    retryer.call(() -> {
        doRealStuff();
      });
  } catch (RetryException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Call never succeeded", e);
  } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    Throwables.propagateIfPossible(e.getCause(), ArithmeticException.class);
    throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected", e);
  }
}
```

Then when you actually call `doStuff`:

```
try {
  doStuff();
} catch(ArithmeticException e) {
  System.err.println("Arithmetic exception caught:");
  e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `doStuff()` or at least knowing what kinds of Exceptions it throws it's hard to answer.

In general, if you have the `Retryer` consider every `Exception` unsuccessful, it will retry and eventuelly stop - but it catches **any** `Throwable` thrown inside the executed code (see [Retryer code](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/rholder/retry/Retryer.java), line 162)

The solution is either:

- If your `doStuff()` only throws an `ArithmeticException` in those cases that result in stopping the Retryer, and that a different kind of Exception marks that a retry is necessary, you can do `retryIfExceptoinOfType(OtherException.class)`. Then, according to the docs [the docs](https://rholder.github.io/guava-retrying/javadoc/2.0.0/com/github/rholder/retry/Retryer.html#call(java.util.concurrent.Callable)

> **Throws:**
>
> `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException` - if the given callable throws an exception, and the rejection predicate considers the attempt as successful. The original exception is wrapped into an `ExecutionException`.

`call()` will throw an `ExecutionException` that you can catch outside of the Retryer and inspect the wrapped Exception.

- If `ArithmeticExcpetion` is all `doStuff()` will throw, and that also indicates that the Retryer should retry, then you can write a custom `StopStrategy` that throw an `ArithmeticExpcetion`, it is catched nowhere in the Retryer.

However I advise you to completele rewrite your code, your data flow seems a bit broken. If an `ArithmeticExpcetion` (or actually even **any** Exception, as you specify `Exception.class` in the retryIf ) is to be expected, it should not *also* be unexpected and need special handling.